# Call Grub (MBR) from Linux

Tags: assembly, mbr

I need an ASSEMBLER tool.

I need to switch processor from protected mode to real mode.

I need to copy the first 512 bytes of First Sector of first drive (it's an SSD now) to 0000:07c0 and JMP to that location.

In effect I need to boot Grub2 from Linux by-passing BIOS POST to save a few seconds in `sudo reboot`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest chainloading a boot manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42790410/simplest-chainloading-a-boot-manager). It includes code.

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate it indeed answers my goal.